# Firebase Push Notification Increase Badge Count When Receive Notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I am using iOS 10 with swift 2.3 I need to increase badge count when receiving new notification from firebase. I have code to increase badge count

```
let badgeCount: Int = BadgeCount + 1
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
```

But I don't know where to use it to make it work correctly.

Comment: badge count is generally maintained by backend services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using push notification, then you cannot maintain the count from your app. You need to write this logic server side because your app will not come to know about push until and unless user taps on it.
Second option is using silent notifications. Silent notifications are delivered to your app and then you need to trigger local push and maintain the badge count.
Disadvantage of silent notification is, you won't receive silent notification if user kills your app.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Firebase push notification we just need to enable iOS badge and include badge count before sending. In `AppDelegate.Swift`, in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` function we need to add

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

Comment: If you make badge count = 0 on app launch, then all the notifications will be cleared. There is a possibility that user might not have read those notifications or he taps on one notification, then also remaining notifications will get cleared from notification tray. I would suggest not to make badge count as zero on app launch.

Comment: How to make notification badge to 0 without removing notifications from notification tray @Coder

Comment: Is it mandatory to show badge number?  I'll recommend not to show badge number. You can reset badge using push/silent notification. In payload set 0 for badge parameter.

Answer (score 4):

**SWIFT 4**
(AppDelegate)

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to clear badge count and not to remove notifications , then you can use

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1
```